# ¿Cómo subir imágenes a mysql con php?

Tags: php, html, sql, base-de-datos

quisiera saber cómo podría subir imágenes a una base de datos para poder hacer usuarios en mi página web, espero que me ayuden es para la escuela, gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo que no subas la imagen dentro de la base de datos, la imagen puede ir en un directorio por ejemplo y en la ddbb solo guardas la ruta de la imagen para que luego la aplicación web cree el URL. Guardar binarios (imagen) en la ddbb la sobrecarga y genera un re proceso adicional sin necesidad.

Comment: yo te recomiendo que no subas las imágenes al Mysql, súbelas a un directorio y sólo subes a Mysql el nombre o ubicación del archivo y ya lo jalas desde ahí. Es la mejor manera de hacerlo

Comment: Las preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo. Lee [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic) para más información y ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

En la base de datos tienes que crear una tabla con un campo medium-blob que puede almacenar creo que 16 mb o un long blob para archivos más grandes
En tu formulario HTML tienes que poner como atributo `enctype='multipart/form-data'`

En el archivo php seria algo más o menos así

```
<?php
include("./conexion.php");
//Titulo de la imagen
$titulo=$_POST["tit"];
//Descripción de la imagen
$descripcion=$_POST["descrip"];
//Verifica si se ha subido la imagen
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"])){
//Verifica si el el formato de la imagen es JPEG o JPG
if ($_FILES["imagen"]["type"]=="image/jpeg"|| $_FILES["imagen"]["type"]=="image/jpg" ){
    //Obtiene información de la imagen
    $info=getimagesize($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"]);

    //Obtiene el formato de imagen nuevamente para asignarlo al nombre
    $tipo=$_FILES["imagen"]["type"];
    //Asigna un nombre aleatorio
    $nom=md5(time().rand(500,100000),FALSE)."_.$tipo";


    //Guarda el contenido de la imagen codificado con base 64 
    $imagenEscapes=base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"]));

    //Inserta en la base de datos 
    $consulta="INSERT INTO imagenes SET IMAGEN='$imagenEscapes', TIPO='$tipo', ALTO='$info[1]', ANCHO='$info[0]', NOMBRE='$nom', TITULO='$titulo', DESCRIPCION='$descripcion'";
     $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
    //Si la consulta imprime el error de la consulta 
    if(!$consulta){
       print("MySQLI Error:".mysqli_error($conexion));
    }
    //De lo contrario regresa al index
    else{
        header("location: ../index.php");
    }
}
}
?>
```